# Array to string conversion

Tags: yii2, yii

На localhost всё работает без проблем. Решил залить на vds в итоге при авторизации вылазиит ошибка, если повторно в браузере в окно адреса нажать Enter, ошибки нет. Когда заново авторизацию прохожу, всё по новой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А на локалхост работает без проблем потому что `error_reporting` отключен.

Comment: в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: другие ошибки на локалхост отображает

Comment: Какое-то из значений в отмеченной строке является массивом судя по всему.